# What is the derivative of $|x|^2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, absolute-value

I've thought that since

$$ f(x) = |x|^2 = 
\begin{cases}
(-x)^2, & \mbox{if } x \leq 0 \\
x^2, & \mbox{if } x > 0
\end{cases} = 
\begin{cases}
x^2, & \mbox{if } x \leq 0 \\
x^2, & \mbox{if } x > 0
\end{cases},$$

the derivative of $f(x)$ would be $2x$. However, it seems that it is, actually, only differentiable at $x = 0$. But why?

Comment: $|x|^2=x^2$, I'm not sure why you think it is only differentiable at zero.

Comment: What makes you think it's only differentiable at $0$?

Comment: As a _complex_ function, $|x|^2$ is differentiable only at $x = 0$. Might that be where you heard that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, folks. I was talking about $x$ as a complex variable. So, if $x = a + i\ b$ and $f(x) = u(a,b) + i\ v(a,b) =|x|^2 = a^2 + b^2 $, then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial a} = 2a$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial b} = 0$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial b} = 2b$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial a} = 0$. Therefore, the Cauchy-Riemann condition is only satisfied when $a = b = 0$, so the function is only analytic at $z=0$.

P.S.: I've made this confusion because I had calculated the derivative of |x|^2  using Mathematica (without saying if it was either real or complex) and the answer was not defined for $x\ne 0$. So, I've thought that this was also the answer for real variables too.

Answer (score 3):

You're right. $|x|^2 = x^2$, so $|x|^2$ is differentiable wherever $x^2$ is, and their derivatives are the same.

Comment: I'd also add that a close relative, $f: x \to x*|x|$, has as derivative $f': x \to 2|x|$ everywhere (even zero). It is however not differentiable twice at zero.